# Why doesn't super(Thread, self).__init__() work for a threading.Thread subclass?

Tags: python, multithreading

Every object I know of in Python can take care of its base class initialization by calling:

```
super(BaseClass, self).__init__()
```

This doesn't seem to be the case with a subclass of `threading.Thread`, since if I try this in `SubClass.__init__()`, I get:

```
RuntimeError: thread.__init__() not called
```

What gives this error?  I looked at the source for `threading.Thread` and it looks like that `__init__` method should set `Thread.__initialized = True`.  I see that all examples use the following `__init__`:

```
class YourThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        # whatev else
```

But why?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This works fine:

```
>>> class MyThread(threading.Thread):
...   def __init__(self):
...     super(MyThread, self).__init__()
```

I think your code's bug is that you're passing the **base** class, rather than the **current** class, to `super` -- i.e. you're calling `super(threading.Thread, ...`, and that's just wrong. Hard to say since you don't show your failing code, but that's what I infer obliquely from the language you're using!-)